# how to execute a codeigniter controller method in background

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter's controller function that fetches mails from gmail.

It is taking lot of time so I need to execute that particular controller function in the background so that the user need not wait until all the mails are fetched.

Comment: Here is https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/cli.html

Comment: Are you referring to a client-side solution such as AJAX?

Comment: Either use AJAX as suggested by @MonkeyZeus. A Cronjob or a Queu system like http://iron.io. php can't really run asynchronous.

Comment: I have used Proc_Close (Proc_Open ("php-cli -q test1.php &", Array (), $foo)); where my test1.php has the script to fetch mails and store in the database. If I execute test1.php directly 42 rows are inserted but when I use Proc_Close (Proc_Open ("php-cli -q test1.php &", Array (), $foo)); only 5 rows are inserted. Can someone tell the reason and a solution please.

Answer (score 1):

**Ajax Jquery Way**

*js:*

```
$.ajax({
    url   : "index.php?/MyController/myMethod",
    async : true //change this to false if you hate your users and want them to wait 
}).done(function() {
    alert("EMAIL IS READY! USER DIDN'T WAIT")
});
```

*php:*

```
class MyController extends CI_Controller{

      function myMethod(){
          //do your email stuff
      }

      //if codgeIgniter V2
      function myMethod_get(){
          //do your email stuff
      }

}
```

Comment: what if the user switches to other page while the emails are not yet fetched? The php script (myMethod()) called by ajax still executes?